# Tag usage over time

Tags: discussion, meta, data-explorer

I want to find out the tag usage over time, across all tags.

As my first step I wrote the following query to give me the tag usage for "sql" over time.

```
SELECT --TOP 20 
    convert(varchar, CreationDate, 101),
    COUNT(*) AS questions
 FROM Tags
    INNER JOIN PostTags ON PostTags.TagId = Tags.id
    INNER JOIN Posts ON Posts.ParentId = PostTags.PostId
WHERE 
    Tags.tagname = 'sql'
GROUP BY convert(varchar, CreationDate, 101) 
ORDER BY convert(varchar, CreationDate, 101) ASC
```

Questions:

- Is this the most efficient way to get the usage per day?
- Do you know where I can find the syntax for the Meta queries? https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new?

Comment: To query the meta, just add `meta.` to the site name: http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/new.

Comment: Just a note, that information on data.SE can be up to a week out of date. It is only updated once a week.

Comment: I modified your query slightly to add graph rendering functionality: [query at data-explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/198335/number-of-post-per-day-for-one-tag#graph)

Answer (score 1):

It is a way to get the usage per day. I wouldn't convert to a varchar but to a date because that enable SEDE to create a graph, which was also mentioned by [Daniel](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255313/tag-usage-over-time#comment33617_255313).

My attempt can be found [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/412908#graph)

```sql
SELECT 
    dateadd(m, -datediff(m, CreationDate, getdate()),getdate()),
    COUNT(*) AS questions
 FROM Tags
    INNER JOIN PostTags ON PostTags.TagId = Tags.id
    INNER JOIN Posts ON Posts.Id = PostTags.PostId
WHERE 
    Tags.tagname = 'sql'
GROUP BY  dateadd(m, -datediff(m, CreationDate, getdate()),getdate())
ORDER BY  dateadd(m, -datediff(m, CreationDate, getdate()),getdate()) ASC
```

Notice how I used date calculations and reduced the clutter to counts per month.

One very significant change I made is in the join. You joined on post.parentid and that basically joined all answer posts for a question. But only questions have tags so you better join the posts.id instead.

You can find the explanation of the SEDE schema in: [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) over on MSE.

On MSE you also find a couple of common/starter queries to show the possibilities of SEDE, like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222544/create-example-reference-queries-on-data-explorer) and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239639/what-sede-examples-would-be-most-useful-to-new-users)